# Kinetic JS Drawing Shapes and Zoom in and out

Tags: drawing, zooming, kineticjs

I am trying to draw different shapes on top of an image using KineticJS and zoom in and out using different buttons, each element works well by itsetlf but when I combine all functions on the same page none works.  Here is the script for drawing a line:

```
 if (drawnewline) {
            document.getElementById('dLine').onclick = function() {
                    layer.on("mousedown", function () {
                        if (moving) {
                            moving = false;
                            layer.draw();
                        } else {
                            var mousePos = stage.getMousePosition();
                            x1 = mousePos.x;
                            y1 = mousePos.y;
                            line = new Kinetic.Line({
                                points: [0, 0, 50, 50],
                                stroke: "red"
                            });
                            layer.add(line);
                            line.getPoints()[0].x = mousePos.x;
                            line.getPoints()[0].y = mousePos.y;
                            line.getPoints()[1].x = mousePos.x;
                            line.getPoints()[1].y = mousePos.y;
                            moving = true;
                            layer.drawScene();
                        }
                    });

                    layer.on("mousemove", function () {
                        if (moving) {
                            var mousePos = stage.getMousePosition();
                            var x = mousePos.x;
                            var y = mousePos.y;
                            line.getPoints()[1].x = mousePos.x;
                            line.getPoints()[1].y = mousePos.y;
                            moving = true;
                            layer.drawScene();
                        }
                    });

                    layer.on("mouseup", function () {
                        moving = false;
                        var mousePos = stage.getMousePosition();
                        x2 = mousePos.x;
                        y2 = mousePos.y;
                        $("#distance").val(calculateDistance(x1, y1, x2, y2));

                    });
                };
            };
```

The complete script can be viewed at http://jsfiddle.net/MEQxq/.  I would appreciate your suggestions, and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by moving "if (drawnewline)" inside getElementById!  Also remove mouse actions for example  layer.off('mousemove');.